# can I use scp in same network(wifi) to send file

Tags: wireless, networking, ssh

while reading about `file transter` in `linux` I got:
We can also move files securely using Secure Copy (scp) between two networked hosts. scp uses the SSH protocol for transferring data.

To copy a local file to a remote system, at the command prompt, type scp  :/home/user/ and press Enter.

and I tried this on one of me peer(in same wifi connection) and I got:

```
anupam@JAZZ:~$ scp data.txt divesh@192.168.1.2:Desktop/
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.2 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
anupam@JAZZ:~$ ssh -p 10022 divesh@192.168.1.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.2 port 10022: Connection refused
anupam@JAZZ:~$ ssh -p 10022 divesh@192.168.1.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.2 port 10022: Connection refused
anupam@JAZZ:~$
```

how can I resolve this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `SCP`

But make sure you have ssh server running on both machine (install it if not installed)

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: You only need `openssh-server` on systems which you're connecting to remotely - `scp` can handle local-to-remote as well.  (The only time you need `openssh-server` on the system you're on, i.e. `JAZZ` in the OP's example, is if you're going to connect ot it from the other "remote" system that isn't `JAZZ`)

Comment: If its 1 way copy from A to B then you need ssh server running on B only, but its also a good idea to have it installed on  A and B, or if you only use A to copy from and to B. But you can not copy from/to A using B unless its stalled on A

Comment: No, it's not a good idea, unless you have your firewall filtering the SSH access to local network traffic only.  Having `openssh-server` on a computer that does not need it is a **security risk** and opens your computer to possible exploitation and breaches.  (As an IT security person, I know this to be fact)

Comment: thanx @ AdigaJo ,it worked now.

Comment: Welcome, And its not really security risk if you have a strong password and/or behind a router.

Comment: @AdigaJo anything that is useless/pointless is a security risk. Having a strong password and being behind a router doesn't mean you're secure.